# Efficient Word List Search

Tags: c#, search, arraylist

I'm making a program that needs to search through an entire word list for a valid word every time a letter is registered (Tens of thounds of words). The catch is, letters dont necessarily come in order. You can register "O", "G", "R" and "F" in this order to spell "frog". Plus, just knowing if there is a valid word is not enough. I have to know which word it is.

So here is the question: Is using IndexOf() method every time a letter is registered my only option? Or there are more efficient ways?
It will be C# by the way.

Thank you in advance

I tried the IndexOf method but going through thousands of words dont seem very efficient.

Comment: Many words share at least a good part of their chars with other words. I doubt you will get really good without even considering order of input for hit probability ...

Comment: You may want to investigate "fuzzy search"...

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching through a large list of words in C# and want to efficiently find the valid words based on registered letters, you might consider using a data structure like a trie (prefix tree). Tries are particularly efficient for searching through sets of strings, making them a good fit for word search scenarios.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TrieNode
{
    public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> Children { get; set; }
    public bool IsEndOfWord { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }

    public TrieNode()
    {
        Children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
        IsEndOfWord = false;
        Words = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class WordTrie
{
    private TrieNode root;

    public WordTrie()
    {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void InsertWord(string word)
    {
        TrieNode node = root;

        foreach (char c in word)
        {
            if (!node.Children.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                node.Children[c] = new TrieNode();
            }

            node = node.Children[c];
        }

        node.IsEndOfWord = true;
        node.Words.Add(word);
    }

    public List<string> FindWordsWithPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        TrieNode node = root;

        foreach (char c in prefix)
        {
            if (node.Children.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                node = node.Children[c];
            }
            else
            {
                // Prefix not found
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        return node.Words;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WordTrie trie = new WordTrie();
        string[] words = { "frog", "apple", "orange", "table", "bat" };

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            trie.InsertWord(word);
        }

        // Example: Searching for words with the prefix "fro"
        List<string> foundWords = trie.FindWordsWithPrefix("fro");

        foreach (string word in foundWords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind that OP does not have a prefix requirement. He explicitly states that letters can come in any order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare by breaking each word into individual characters and adding them to the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<char, HashSet<string>> d;

void Add(string word)
{
    foreach(var ch in word)
    {
        if(!d.TryGetValue(ch, out var hs))
            d.Add(ch, hs = new());
        hs.Add(word);
    }
}
```

Now whenever you receive an input character, you can retrieve all candidate words containing that character from the dictionary above:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetCandidateWords(char ch)
    => d.TryGetValue(ch, out var hs) ? hs : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

To obtain candidate words containing multiple characters, you can use another `HashSet`:

```
var candidates = new HashSet<string>(GetCandidateWords('o'));
candidates.IntersectWith(GetCandidateWords('g'));
candidates.IntersectWith(GetCandidateWords('r'));
candidates.IntersectWith(GetCandidateWords('f'));
```